# Who wins in this two pair situation?

Tags: texas-hold-em

Who wins in this situation. 5 cards are (5)(5)(9)(9)(2). Player 1 has (2)(A). Player 2 has (J)(A).

Answer (score 2):

Poker hands have *exactly five cards*, no more, no less. Both players are playing the hand 9-9-5-5-A. Split pot.